# Is it possible to create a viewport in SVG using a percentage of the minimum of the width and height?

Tags: svg

I want to create a viewport in an SVG file that has 20% taken off two of the sides, one vertically, the other horizontally, where the 20% is the minimum of the width and height. So if the image is wider than it is high the viewport will be 80% of the height and more than 80% of the width. If the image is taller than it is wide the viewport will be 80% of the width and more than 80% of the height. And if the image is square the viewport will be 80% of both the width and the height. I.e. the corner inside the image between the viewport and the outside edge will always be a square, and the size of that square will always be 20% of the minimum of the height and width. Can this even be done?

```
<?xml version="1.0" standalone="no"?>
<!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg11.dtd">
<svg width="600" height="400" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <path d="M 0,0 L 0,400 L 600,400 L 600,0 z" fill="blue"/>
  <svg x="0" y="0" width="80%" height="80%">
    <path d="M 0,0 L 0,400 L 600,400 L 600,0 z" fill="red"/>
    <path d="M 150,50 L 430,220 L 50,270 z" fill="green"/>
  </svg>
</svg>
```

This is what I've got so far but obviously the inner viewport has 80% of the both the width and height (480x320). I want it to be 520x320 initially but for `w1 - w2 == h1 - h2` to always be true. I want the green triangle to scale within whatever space is left to it (i.e. not to preserve the aspect ratio).

Comment: Yes it is possible.  What have you tried?

Answer (score 0):

You can do what you want, but you'll need to use Javascript.

```js
// Get pointers to the outer and inner SVG elements
var outer = document.getElementById("outer");
var inner = document.getElementById("inner");

// Get the dimensions of the outer SVG
var outerW = outer.width.baseVal.value;
var outerH = outer.height.baseVal.value;

// Find the minimum of the width and height and calculate what 20% of it is
var diff = Math.min(outerW, outerH) * 0.2;

// Adjust the size of the inner SVG
inner.setAttribute("width", outerW - diff);
inner.setAttribute("height", outerH - diff);
```

```html
<svg id="outer" width="600" height="400" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <path d="M 0,0 L 0,400 L 600,400 L 600,0 z" fill="blue"/>
  <svg id="inner" x="0" y="0" viewBox="0 0 600 400" preserveAspectRatio="none">
    <path d="M 0,0 L 0,400 L 600,400 L 600,0 z" fill="red"/>
    <path d="M 150,50 L 430,220 L 50,270 z" fill="green"/>
  </svg>
</svg>
```

The inner SVG needs to have a `viewBox` if you want it to scale or stretch.  And if you want its contents to stretch to fixt the 520x320 size, then you need to set `preserveAspectRatio="none"` as I have done above.

Comment: So there's nothing within SVG itself to do this? I haven't looked at programming within SVG yet but one of the first SVGs I saw way back when was a full Tetris implementation! I was hoping to create some SVG files for scalable icons and render them as PNGs before serving them. I'd need to have JavaScript on the server too. I might as well just fiddle with the XML in PHP and save it to a temp file before rendering.

Comment: In the future (eg. when SVG 2 comes out), you might be able to do it withh CSS variables and the CSS `calc()` function.  But not with how things are now.

Comment: So the answer is, purely within SVG, no. Using other tools to modify the SVG, yes. I also don't understand your SVG example. When I try it the red background completely covers the blue one yet when I run your code snippet I can see the blue background as I intended.

Comment: Make sure the script is running after the DOM is ready.  If it is running before the page is completely ready then the script may be failing and modification of the SVG will not be happening.